# How to set POST data to URL and get results in string variable

Tags: url, post

I am trying to get a POST result but the server has block it.
I have tried with

- fsockopen
- curl
- file_get_contents

but I got a same result from the server as an eroor massage of "Access denied" .

Is there any way to get the POST results from the block server.

```
<?php
$post_arr = array ("regno" => "1"); 
    $addr = 'url'; 

    $fp = fsockopen($addr, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
    if (!$fp) { 
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n"; 
    } else { 

        $req = ''; 
        foreach ($post_arr as $key => $value) { 
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
            $req .= "&" . $key . "=" . $value; 
        } 


        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n"; 
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"; 
        $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n"; 
        fwrite($fp, $header); 
        while (!feof($fp)) { 
            echo fgets($fp, 128); 
        } 
        fclose($fp); 
    }  
?>
```

and also

```
<?php
    $postdata = http_build_query( 
        array( 
            'regno' => 1
        ) 
    ); 

    $opts = array('http' => 
        array( 
            'method'  => 'POST', 
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
            'content' => $postdata 
        ) 
    ); 

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts); 

    $result = file_get_contents('url', false, $context); 
    echo $result;
?>
```

Both the above method give me a access denied output.

Comment: Access Denied is access denied. If the server's not letting you in, you're not going to get in. What makes you think you can do antyhign on your end to bypass the server's lockout? If a security guard denies you access to a bank vault, changing the color of your shirt isn't going to change the fact that you're not getting into the vault.

Comment: Does it work manually? If so, you want to use Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug to look at the request headers that are sent, and then use cURL to mimic those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the HTTP_REFERER variable.

```
'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nReferer: http://urltopost\r\n",
```

And if that doesn't work, try to mimic more of the headers. This is what I have from looking at the Network Tab of Chrome Developer Tools:

```
POST /hse/result.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: urlhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 17
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: url
User-Agent: something
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: url
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDASRCTADA=FBHLDODAOCBACEKMNFLJIMGO
```

**Edited** to include working code:
If you replace the $opts definition in your second code snippet with this, it will work. It works for me.

```
$opts = array('http' => 
    array( 
        'method'  => 'POST', 
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                    ."Referer: url\r\n",
        'content' => $postdata 
    ) 
);
```

Full code:

```
<?php 
$postdata = http_build_query( array( 'regno' => 1 ) ); 
$opts = array('http' => array( 'method' => 'POST', 'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" ."Referer: urltopost\r\n", 'content' => $postdata ) );
$context = stream_context_create($opts); 
$result = file_get_contents('urltopost', false, $context);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ansari. I have tried by changing the 'header' too but I got the same result access denied. I am also very new in programmin. Please guide me. Thanking You.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. But it doesnot work. I have change the $opts definition also.

Comment: I don't know what to say - I just checked again, copied your initial code, replaced with my section, and it works for me. I get the result for regno = 1. Re. the code you just pasted, there is a semicolon after results.asp that should not be there.

Comment: I put the full code in my answer now. Save that to a new file and run it. It should work. If not, there's something else that's wrong with your server configuration.

Comment: In that case I have no idea - maybe they blocked your IP or domain or something. Can you try setting up a webserver on your local machine or try from some other domain?

Comment: Thanks ansari for your help. when I uploaded my file to another hosting it works. Once again Thanks Buddy.

Comment: I am very sorry as I am very new in the website, it is asking me for 15 reputation to accept the answer. I will do it leter on. Thanks Ansari.

Comment: You shouldn't need any reputation to accept an answer - you need 15 to upvote it.

Comment: Oh I see at the down portion. Is that "Was this post useful to You?" I am very sorry. I am very new in this form. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm no, there should be a hollow tick mark or something beside this answer. No problem :)

Comment: I am very Sorry sir I am unable to find any of that. Please give ur email address I will sent the screen shot. Thanks.

Comment: That's funny - right beside the top of this answer, do you see vertically an up arrow, then a big zero, then a down arrow? Underneath the down arrow there should be a tick mark. Try using a different browser maybe if you don't see it.

Comment: Very Very Thanks I got it. and I have done it. Once angain thanks for your valuable help.