# how to get database data from a web page using PHP

Tags: php

In this case i want to extract data from this URL:

`https://www.aeropuertosgap.com.mx/es/index.php?option=com_infovuelo&Itemid=746`

I did use `HTML_DOM` but it (obviously) only extracts html data, it is just flight information!

Comment: reading the question... WTF?

Comment: What information have you been asked to extract via this URL that you are not getting currently?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really access another person's database directly unless the airline provide some sort of API to help you access it.

The only real way I think you could do this is if you POST data to the form and then filter through the HTML and get the required data.

See [How to set POST data to URL and get results in string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577316/how-to-set-post-data-to-url-and-get-results-in-string-variable)

From looking at the HTML of the webpage, I can see the form is posted to: index.php?option=com_infovuelo&Itemid=746 and the results are under the div with id "info-vuelo-result".

Good Luck!

P.S. This is one weird question!

Comment: This is the only way. Honestly, if he tries to access directly into the database, that is illegal. Either the API, scraping the web page and that's it. Using the AJAX calls is illegal too, as far as I know (saw about this a few months ago).

Comment: Is it??? Can you send me the link please?

Comment: I would have actually suggested AJAX, but realized they did not use AJAX. Good thing I didn't

Comment: I would send the link, but it was in written in the answer of a question here on SO. Due to the high number of answers and questions, that is almost impossible today.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with [Yahya Uddin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3006737/yahya-uddin). You need to write robot, sending form data, then parse the response, using DOM queries.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a theory question or you want us to develop the code for you?

IF THIS IS A THEORY QUESTION:

well I did something like this with a calendar where the provider did not have any API or anything else, so what I did was get the content with `file_get_contents` and using `preg_match` and `preg_replace` I achieved what I wanted to do with it.

Also check `CURL`.